# .svg not sharp on retina displays

Tags: css, svg, cursor, retina-display

I am trying to have a sharp custom cursor on a retina display, so I thought using a .svg would make it … But it does not… Unfortunately … Does someone have an idea what's wrong in my thinking?

See the JSFiddle to test it … I have tested it on a IMac 5K Retina Display in Safari …

```
#div {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black;}
#div:hover {cursor: url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/ndxzsite/img/cursor_next.svg), move;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zju0e871/

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your cursor a little larger? People seem to have problems with SVGs smaller than 20x20 px.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42438/svg-images-showing-up-blurry-in-safari-in-any-size-smaller-than-20-px

[Firefox SVG graphics blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954028/firefox-svg-graphics-blurry)

Answer (score 0):

It is a known missing feature on webkit browsers and Firefox.
The case is open on the Chromium code review:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=325565

Maybe a PNG resized down? Need to test it.