# Low quality of SVG cursors (CSS)

Tags: html, css, svg, cursor

I have a problem with quality (sharpness) of svg cursors. It is really low. I tried to set different shape-rendering values but it does not help.

Example of use:

```
cursor: url('./question.svg') 4 4, auto !important;
```

And svg:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>
    question mark
  </title>
  <path d="M469.3 256a213.3 213.3 0 1 1-426.6 0 213.3 213.3 0 0 1 426.6 0zm-256-64a42.7 42.7 0 1 1 61.2 38.5 69.9 69.9 0 0 0-39.8 62.8 21.3 21.3 0 1 0 42.6 0c0-10.3 6-19.8 15.7-24.4A85.3 85.3 0 1 0 170.7 192a21.3 21.3 0 1 0 42.6 0zM256 405.3a32 32 0 1 0 0-64 32 32 0 0 0 0 64z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
```

I think you can easily reproduce it because it happens always.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to make things clearer as possible? However, I checked this link <https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/> and the more-parameters cursor property has two parameters, for example: `svg:hover { cursor: url(./question.svg), auto; }`. So... what are the `4` expected to do?

Comment: @xKobalt: URL and coordinates, with a keyword fallback.

Comment: @Sheppard25 I don't have the quality problems you mention

Comment: Please let us know which browser and device you are using, because I just tested on Windows using Chrome and Edge and they both seem to render the cursor just fine. @xKobalt the 4s are coordinates for an alternative hotspot: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: No problem here either. Chrome & Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: @jboot I am using Chrome 83 and MacOS

Comment: @xKobalt how to make a screenshot with cursor?

Comment: It depends by softwares and operating systems, for example this guide can help you on Windows 10: <https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/include-mouse-cursor-windows-10-screenshot>

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, on Chrome, FF, Safari on MAC. Safari is (for once) best quality, but still not as crisp as with a png as seen here: https://gist.github.com/dsdsdsdsdsds/bd142334efcd81f0b30e

Comment: I think I remember a similar issue I had back in the days when I owned a MacBook. If I recall correctly it’s a rendering issue due to the fact that you’re using a Retina display (built in MacBook display) and a “regular” display (external monitor). I think you can verify that the cursor looks better when shown on the native screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug in Chromium. I don't own HighDPI displays like Apple's Retina display and that is why I cannot confirm the issue. However, I did find this bug on Chromium's bug tracker that remains unresolved:

[Issue 325565: Custom SVG cursors are blurry on a HighDPI display](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=325565)

Chrome, Brave and even the latest Edge browser are based on Chromium so I expect that they all have the same flaw. This should also explain why @rassoh reports that Safari behaves differently by showing a slightly better quality. Safari is not Chromium based, but Chromium was originally based on Safari/WebKit. I do not know why FireFox seems to have the same issue, as reported by @rassoh. Though it might have something to do with both teams overlooking the case of properly implementing SVG cursor rendering in HighDPI screens, which was a rare scenario at that time.

I am afraid that I do not know how to solve the issue other than waiting for this bug to be fixed. Perhaps you can achieve better results using an optimized PNG image.

**Edit:** I found a similar question where people seem to draw the same conclusion:

[.svg not sharp on retina displays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432400/svg-not-sharp-on-retina-displays)